# Getting name from the email address in python

Tags: python

I have a text file in which there are email addresses in the following format:

```
some.name@somehost.com
```

or

```
some_name@somehost
```

How can I split the string to get some & name? I tried the following code, but it appears I can only use one character (just the **@** or just the **.**).Is there a way to do it in one statement? Thanks.

```
name = email.split('@', '.')
```

Comment: Yeah, that's not how split works. You should really read the docs and see what each argument does. `name = email.split('@')[0].split('.')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following:

```
email = "some.name@somehost.com"

name, _, _ = email.partition("@")  # returns before @, @, and after @
splitname = name.split(".")        # splits on .

print(splitname)
```

`["some", "name"]`

Answer (score 1):

In case of email addresses with no predefined structure, you can use: https://github.com/intuit/email-decomposer.